# How to add running total/ counter to C# console application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oop, object

My application is taking user input (bowling scores) and averages them out. The issue I am coming to is the requirement of allowing the user to stop at any time. I placed 10 int variables and assumed one will not be calculating over 10. My question, is how do I keep a running total/ tally, so that if the user only inputs 2 scores to average, that I only divide by 2? Thanks for any help.

```
Console.WriteLine("Please input the score of game 1: ");
g1 = ReadLine();
game1 = int.Parse(g1);
Console.WriteLine("Would you like to add more scores? Press 'n' to continue to averaging, press any other key to continue!");
playagain = ReadLine();
if(playagain =="n")
{
    calculating(); 
}
Console.Clear();
```

This is how I coded the program. Do I create a variable, and assign itself inside of a while statement, to declare if any other buttons are pressed (program continues to another user input for game 2), to add 1 to the variable?

Comment: You could use a `List` and then divide by the `Count`.

Comment: Use a collection (`List<int>`) to keep an arbitrary number of inputs

Answer (score 1):

Use a `List<int>` collection to store the scores, then either

1) Divide the sum total of the values in the list and divide by the list's count property:

```
var scores = new List<int>();
int total = 0;

foreach(var score in scores)
{
  total += score;
}

var average = total / scores.Count;
```

2) Use LINQ's `.Average()` method to quickly get the average of all the values in the list:

```
var scores = new List<int>();
var average = scores.Average();
```

Naturally use any data types or conversions needed to obtain the level of accuracy you need/desire.

Comment: the use of LINQ is cleaner

Comment: @Kokombads Absolutely, but not everyone knows how to use it so I included the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 0; 
while(playagain != "n")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please input the score of game 1: ");
    g1 = ReadLine();
    game1 += int.Parse(g1);
    count++;
    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to add more scores? Press 'n' to continue to averaging, press any other key to continue!");
    playagain = ReadLine();        
    Console.Clear();
}
```

the count variable will keep a running total on the number of inputs and the game1 variable will continue to add the scores up.

**UPDATE for question asked;**

```
class OtherClass{
   public int Counter {set; get;}
  .
  .//other logic
  .
}
OtherClass otherClass = new OtherClass();
int count = 0; 
while(playagain != "n")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please input the score of game 1: ");
    g1 = ReadLine();
    game1 += int.Parse(g1);
    count++;
    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to add more scores? Press 'n' to continue to averaging, press any other key to continue!");
    playagain = ReadLine();        
    Console.Clear();
}
otherClass.Counter = count;
```

Comment: I had used this method, but was looking to call upon all my variables AND counter in another class, to calculate the totals. My issue is that the other class sees the counter value as 0, as it is assigned before the class. Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can push into a list and use Sum() and Average() extensions. TO keep aceepting scores, you can use while loop

```
    Console.WriteLine("Please input the score of game 1: ");
    List<int> scores = new List<int>();
    int game1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    scores.Add(game1);
    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to add more scores? Press 'n' to continue to averaging, press any other key to continue!");
    string playagain = Console.ReadLine();
    while(playagain != "n")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please input the score of next game: ");
        scores.Add(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to add more scores? Press 'n' to continue to averaging, press any other key to continue!");
        playagain = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Total is " + scores.Sum());
    Console.WriteLine("Average is " + scores.Average());
    Console.Clear();
```